# Counting number of occurrences in several files

Tags: shell, unix, solaris

I want to check the number of occurrences of, let's say, the character '[', recursively in all the files of a directory that have the same extension, e.g. *.c. I am working with the SO Solaris in Unix.

I tried some solutions that are given in other posts, and the only one that works is this one, since with this OS I cannot use the command `grep -o`:

```
sed 's/[^x]//g' filename | tr -d '012' | wc -c
```

Where x is the occurrence I want to count. This one works but it's not recursive, is there any way to make it recursive?

Comment: You can make it recursive for a specific directory by replacing `filename` with `*` (for current directory) or `/dir/*` for another directory or even `/dir1/*.txt /dir2/*.txt` to scan two directories. If you want to search recursivelly for all directories then using `find` is the correct way.

Comment: Thank you George, you are totally right and I want the latter option so I used find as Grisha suggested me to do and worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a recursive listing from `find` and execute commands with its `-exec` argument.

I'd suggest like:

```
find . -name '*.c' -exec cat {} \; | tr -c -d ']' | wc -c
```

The `-c` argument to `tr` means to use the opposite of the string supplied -- i.e. in this case, match everything *but* `]`.

The `.` in the find command means to search in the current directory, but you can supply any other directory name there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have nawk installed. Then you can just:

```
nawk '{a+=gsub(/\]/,"x")}END{print a}' /path/*
```

Comment: nawk doesn't work very well with my OS but thank you anyway for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a snippet code itself. I suggest you to run the following:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="[") n++} END{print n}' *.c
```

This will search for "[" in all files in the present directory and print the number of occurrences.

Comment: I tried this solution but it seems it prints the number of files where this occurrence happens, and I want to know how many times the character appears in all the files.

Comment: Are you sure about? Because I have use the same code and it showed me...10, even when the directory contains only 5 files only.

Comment: Yes I used that code with one file that had 6 occurrences of the character ']' and it showed me 1. Then I created another file with the same number of occurrences and showed me 2, so my conclusion was it only counted the files in which the character appeared at least one time, but I don't know why we have different solutions maybe I'm doing something wrong, thank you for your reply!